# How to convert the position in JTextPane with HTMLDocument to position in JTextPane string text

Tags: java, html, string, swing, jtextpane

I have an application in java swing containing `JTextPane` with `HTMLDocument`. Let's say I set text of the pane to:

```
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>
       <p style="margin-top: 0">
            I have a problem now.
       </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

So I see the text "I have a problem now." on the pane.

Let's assume that I clicked on a pane and the caret was set between 'p' and 'r' in "problem" word. In this situaction if I call `getCaretPosition` on my `JTextPane` it will return 10 (if I count well :) ).

Now knowing this position I would like to convert this position to the position in html string writen above (which is 94 again if I count well :) )
How to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [caret position into the html of JEditorPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866369/caret-position-into-the-html-of-jeditorpane)

Comment: Actually it's not possible. Html is used to build Document (model) but the model don't keep offsets in original string. Imagine the same 2 tags wit 1 space betwenn, with 2 spaces between and without space. HTMLDocument is the same for all 3 cases.

Comment: Oh man ! If you knew how much I worked on this subject... But lucky you, I have found a solution for that. I'll put you an answer when I have 2 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to understand that in html you can't keep the logic of "caret position". As StanislavL told you, it would make no sense as `Hello` can be translated as well by `<html><body>Hello</body></html>` than by `<html>    <body>Hello</body>      </html>`. How would you know in this case which position corresponds to what ?

The mistake is to try to compare the JTextPane text content with the HTML conversion of it. Instead, you should compare the HTMLDocument with the DOM. So, first thing, you need an html parser like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Once you have added JSoup to your project, you can very easily make the parallel between your html and your JTextPane content.

You can get the html with this method :

```
public static String getHTMLContent(HTMLDocument htmlDoc, int startOffset, int length) {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try {
        new HTMLEditorKit().write(writer, htmlDoc, startOffset, length);
    } catch (IOException | BadLocationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Editeur.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    String html = writer.toString();
    return html;
}
```

You can then parse it with Jsoup :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.getElementById("myId");//get the element by its ID
```

So, now, if you want to locate a specific element from the HTMLDocument in the resulting html, what you need to do is to surround it with a `<span>` that you will give an ID to, and then get it with `getElementById`. To do so, you can use `HTMLEditorKit.insertHTML` :

```
(new HTMLEditorKit()).insertHTML(htmlDoc, pos, "<span id='myId'>element of interest</span>", 0, 0, Tag.SPAN);
```

For instance, to get the location of the selected text, you can do :

```
    if (getSelectedText() != null && getSelectedText().length()>0) {
        try {
            String selectedText = getSelectedText()
            htmlDoc.remove(getSelectionStart(), this.getSelectedText().length());
            (new HTMLEditorKit()).insertHTML(htmlDoc, pos, "<span id='myId'>"+selectedText+"</span>", 0, 0, Tag.SPAN);
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Editeur.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Now you can easily get the part you're interested or with `getElementById` from Jsoup, or by `HTMLDocument.getElement(id)` from Java.

I can give more details on specific points if needed.